# What are the best way for powerless individuals to earn power and control over a city?

Tags: law

A very small group of social outcasts desire to earn more power within a city in order to improve their situation from the inside. What would be the best course of action?

Comment: Hmm, This question is undoubtedly going to attract some Votes To Close. Mostly, The laws preventing them from being recognized as having rights are undefined. The social aspects as to why they are treated as having no rights are undefined. The temporary base aspect in many ways is at odds with having us provide goals (which is too story based probably). In reality a question about how to have a robot race gain acknowledgement as having true sentience is probably the right question to kickstart yourself on how to judicially give them rights.

Comment: I think this has some promise, you just need to refine down to a specific problem that your setting needs solved instead of a sweeping "how do I start?" Some inspiration could be gleaned from learning what steps women had to do for their right-to-vote in the US for example.

Comment: It looks like you're asking a question about a story set in a world rather than about building a fictional world.

Comment: Is the goal *to obtain rights*? That leads to one set of actions. Or is the goal *to initiate a revolution*? That leads to another set of actions. There is a bit of overlap between the two, but also a great deal of difference.

Comment: @ITAlex I am not sure if it is a good place to answer, but the story does have an answer to why they have no rights. It is simply because nobody knows they are sentient in the first place! They think they are merely machines, like a computer. 
And it might be for the better, as the idea behind using robots is that they are like slaves 'but can't feel', so it is alright. It's cheaper and easier to have ethical slaves than having regular human workers that have needs and do feel (the setting's reasoning, not mine).

Will that help the question, though? Maybe I should just redo it

Comment: @user535733 Oh, my. I actually.. am not sure. In the story, these robots want to break free from thee system that is engineered to make them miserable (there's a reason for this). They want to be free in a world that does not know and does not want to acknowledge they are sentient. Revolting or obtaining rights are two ways to achieve this, but the robots in the story who are leading the movement see no hope in the later.

I should have worded it like that, probably...

Comment: @sphennings How bad is that? It is true there's defintely a world already settled here, but it's not so developed that it does not require more worldbuilding. The town I talk of defintely requires it.

What did I do wrong? Should I have been less specific?

Comment: You're asking for the goals of two individuals in your story. To me that seems like Something that is story dependent rather than a question about the facts of your world. Perhaps the two robots are focused on big unrealistic goals, perhaps all the want is 8 hours for work, 8 hours for rest, 8 hours for recreation, or perhaps this revolution is motivated by something much more personal like a vendetta against a particular overseer. It's up to you to figure out what goals make sense for your story.

Comment: Having read your edit I think your question still isn't a good fit for this site. You're asking us to create your character's plan without knowing your characters, or anything about the world in which they live. "Best course of action" is highly dependent upon the fine details of your characters motivations, situation, and personal values, none of which we know, and none of which has to do with the world they live in and everything to do with who they are as individuals. For us to be answer this question your world will already need to be built, which defeats the purpose of asking it here.

Comment: I think this question can be adapted, if it can be clarified: Something more along the lines of *How does a powerless and oppressed group achieve X?*  Then you must define the methods of oppression. Remember that most discrimination and oppression often has a goal (like an exploitable labor force and class stratification), and isn't itself the goal.

Comment: @user535733 I just edited it to that! I did not add methods of oppression but changed the term to 'outcasts'. that should serve the question, right? I think what matters is that it gets the point across that these individuals have next to no influence or resources of their own.

Comment: Please read through our [help]. Worldbuilding (on-topic) is about the development and consistent use of rules and systems defining a fictional world of your own creation wherein an infinite number of stories may be told. Storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances, plot, and character choices and/or actions.

Answer (score 3):

**Robot sex.**

These two robots are indignant that robots cant have sex.  Their hideout is full of porno and they constantly read adult magazines and devise scenarios involving robots that can have sex.  The revolution they plan is that robots be reprogrammed and also augmented to make sex possible.  One of them (under a pseudonym) draws an cartoon for the local alternative newspaper called "Robot that can have sex".  It has a small following; people like it because it is funny.  The author does not know it is funny because it does not have a sense of humor.

The robots are not very creative and all of their ideas are from mainstream vanilla porno.  The year is 1996 and their magazines are from a convenience store in their small town.  The human looking one goes into 7-11 and buys porno magazines; also snacks so as not to attract attention.  The snacks pile up in their hideout because robots cannot eat.

In the end it turns out neither of these robots actually want for themselves to be altered so that they are able to have sex.  But they think that other robots should have that right if they choose.

Comment: What on earth....?

Comment: OK... what this supposed to be an answer/comment to the [OP's earlier question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/189114/40609)?

Comment: @JBH: yeah.  Two robots without rights planning a revolution.  But I still like the idea.

Comment: For the love of all that's holy... I did NOT see that coming! ***I'm not worthy!***